# Technology behind [crawlera](http://crawlera.com)(What tools the use to download page content)

Tags: python-3.x, curl, web-crawler, http-status-code-404, urllib

I usually use urllib module in python to scrap data.

Certain websites are blocking to download the page content they are throwing 404 error but the website is live.

In such cases I use crawler proxies.

I wonder what tools and technologies they use for blacklist the website to make this work from 404 to 200

Could any one have idea behind it?

Comment: I don't understand your rejection of my [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7989040) - was it maybe by mistake?

Comment: Hi @Wolf yeah in title you edite crawlera to crawler but crawlera is the actually word

Comment: I see. [A] and [S] are adjacent keys, so I expected the same typo I often do. BTW: the reason for the rejection was strange... As to make the question more understandable, wouldn't it be good to repeat [**crawlera**](http://crawlera.com/) in the text (maybe with a reference link added)?

Comment: Great idea..will appove it with some eidts

Comment: Hi @Wolf i have edited the question since i rejected that i could not approve your..anyways thanks for the guidance

Comment: The link in the title doesn't work as you see, the link syntax isn't available there. I think it's better to start the **text** with an introductory sentence about your observations of crawlera.